# How do you use subtraction while also using a percent?

Tags: python

I am trying to subtract a certain percent away from the total cost, but I am finding difficulties. Here is the code:

```
cost = cost - 20%
```

Python says there is a syntax error.

Comment: Do you mean `cost * 0.8`?...

Comment: cost = cost - cost * 20/100

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting 20% is the same as multiplying by 80%, or 0.8:

```
cost *= 0.8
```

Comment: cost *= 1 - 20/100.0

Answer (score 1):

To be precise to answer the question, a response should be following:

```
pct = 20
cost = cost - cost * pct/100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting 20% of the cost from existing value can be done in one line, as follows:

```
cost -= (0.2 * cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

You method for calculating cost percentage is wrong.

You can calculate 20% of cost by `cost * (20/100)`.

But to do it in your code you could use :

```
cost = cost * 0.8
```

or

```
cost = cost - (cost * (20/100))
```